# Dealing with lunar regolith

Tags: the-moon, nasa, crewed-spaceflight, regolith

NASA has announced its intention to return astronauts to the Moon by 2024. Various other questions and answers here address the many dangers and difficulties posed by the fine and abrasive particles of lunar regolith (possible health issues from inhalation; damage to moving parts, lenses, etc., due to its abrasive quality; damage to electrical systems due to its static charge; temperature-control problems due to the surface-darkening effect of clinging dust; and more). So the question is this: Has NASA worked out methods of solving these problems so that regolith particles will not be a hazard to a future manned lunar mission?

Comment: Check out questions tagged "dust" https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust Some are applicable.

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful.